# How to retrieve the amount of values according to a range of values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'd like some help with Oracle SQL. Let's suppose the following example with two tables:

[image]

There is a way to know how many boxes there are in each range according to the Size of the boxes like this:

```
 Small   3 
 Medium  1
 Large   1
```

I'm trying the following sentence, but it does't work fine:

```
SELECT Sizes.description, COUNT(*) FROM Sizes, Packets WHERE 
Packets.Size BETWEEN SUBSTR(Sizes.range,1,2) 
AND SUBSTR(Sizes.range,4)
GROUP BY Sizes.description;
```

Comment: Is there a reason that your `range` column is a string with two non-atomic elements?  It would make much more sense (and make your queries much easier) to have two columns `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` than to have to parse the `range` column every time.  Of course, when you want to display the ranges, it would be trivial to generate the string `lower_bound || '-' || upper_bound`.

Comment: Hi! The only reason is that the exercise has the column with this format and I can't change that.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3):

You should modify the sizes table to have a minimum and maximum size:

```
alter table sizes add minsize number;
alter table sizes add maxsize int;

update sizes
    set minsize = CAST(SUBSTR(range, 1, INSTR(range, '-') - 1 as number),
        maxsize = CAST(SUBSTR(range, INSTR(range, '-') + 1) as number;
```

Then use a regular `join`:

```
select s.range, count(*)
from packets p left join
     sizes s
     on p.size between s.minsize and s.maxsize
group by s.range
order by max(s.minsize);
```

You can do the same thing with a CTE, but fixing the table is the better idea:

```
with s as (
      select s.*, 
             CAST(SUBSTR(range, 1, INSTR(range, '-') - 1 as number) as minsize,
             CAST(SUBSTR(range, INSTR(range, '-') + 1) as maxsize
      from sizes
     )
select s.range, count(*)
from packets p left join
     s
     on p.size between s.minsize and s.maxsize
group by s.range
order by max(s.minsize);
```

Comment: @user2233540 . . . The suggestion is to add two more columns, not to change the definition of the existing column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select nvl(s.description,'UNKNOWN'),count(*) 
from packets p left join s 
on p.size between to_number(regexp_substr(s.range,'^[^-]+')) 
and to_number(regexp_substr(s.range,'[^-]+$'))
group by s.description
```